# Views are invisible after they was added into ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, view, viewgroup

I'm adding views programatically into `FrameLayout`:

```
public class PixelGridView extends FrameLayout {
...
     public void addViewWithoutCoords(TableView view, int column, int row) {
            float x = column * mCellSideSize;
            float y = row * mCellSideSize;

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                view.setLayoutParams(lp);

            view.setLeft(0);
            view.setTop(0);

            view.setX(x);
            view.setY(y);
            view.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            addView(view);
        }
...
}
```

However, all they are somehow invisible. `getChildCount()` returns count with all of them. `getVisibility()` for each added view also returns `VISIBLE`.

I can drag'n'drop such views from another `ViewGroup` into my `Framelayout` and when I do this, all  earlier added views become visible.

`view` layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivTable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ivTableName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/style_table_grey"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Even If I add new view without drag everything become visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item view of the `FrameLayout` and `RelativeLayout` can be overlapping. If two item views are in the same positions of `FrameLayout`, the first loaded item will be covered by the later item.

Comment: Do you mean `RelativeLayout` views can be under `FrameLayout`?

Comment: You've made my day)) I placed code into 'ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()' and that's it)

Comment: I mean  all the item views that in the `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` will be overlapped or corvered by each other if they are in the same position.

Comment: @Lay'O I'm glad to hear it ：)

Answer (score 0):

Try turn on the show layout bounds in developer option of your android devices,and find the position of your item.

Comment: It shows that no view is inside my container (but getChildCount() returns them). I tried to call invalidate() but it didn't help